# Generic type and ?: operator doesn't work

Tags: c#, generics, ternary-operator

Can anyone explain why this code fails when using `?` operator but works with if statement?

The code below compiles without errors. It throws an exception when I run it.

```
    var myClass = new MyClass<string>();

    string tString;
    //this works fine
    if (myClass.HasValue)
    {
        tString = myClass;
    }
    else
    {
        tString = null;
    }
    //this throws Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    tString = myClass.HasValue ? myClass : null;

    class MyClass<T>
    {
        private T value;
        public T Value
        {
            get
            {
                if(value == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Value cannot be null");
                }

                return value;
            }
            set { this.value = value; }
        }
        public static implicit operator T(MyClass<T> x)
        {
            return x.value;
        }
        public bool HasValue
        {
            get { return value != null; }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
tString = myClass.HasValue ? myClass : null;
```

Here, we've got a ternary. A ternary has a type, which is determined from the two arguments. The compiler looks at `myClass` and `null`, sees that they're compatible (they can both be converted to a `MyClass<string>`), and determines that the type of the ternary is `MyClass<string>`.

If `myClass.HasValue` is `false`, then we hit the `null` branch of the ternary. We then get ourselves a `MyClass<string>` instance which is `null`. We then need to convert that to a `string`: to do this, the compiler calls your implicit operator but passes in `null`. That causes your `NullReferenceException` because you access `x.value` but `x` is `null`.

This doesn't happen with the `if/else` because we never construct a `MyClass<string>` which is `null`. Instead, we assign `null` directly to the `string`.

This simpler example causes the same exception for the same reason:

```
MyClass<string> myClass = null;
string s = myClass;
```

You can also see this by forcing the type of the ternary to be `string` rather than `MyClass<string>`, by doing:

```
tString = myClass.HasValue ? myClass : (string)null;
```

or

```
tString = myClass.HasValue ? (string)myClass : null;
```

In this case the exception doesn't occur.

---

The OP commented that this doesn't happen for an explicit operator. This is wrong: it does.

```
tString = (string)(myClass.HasValue ? myClass : null);
```

This throws the same exception, for the same reason.

If instead you do:

```
tString = myClass.HasValue ? (string)myClass : null;
```

Then you're falling into the same case as I described earlier, because you never create a `MyClass<string>` which is null, and so you never try and convert this `null` `MyClass<string>` into a `string`.

Comment: Was going to comment along these lines, but you've both beaten me to it and explained it better than I would have I think.

Comment: I was going to add that it only happens for implicit conversion when explicit is used it doesn't happen

Comment: My bad it doesn't happen when tString = myClass.HasValue ? (string)myClass : null; or tString = myClass.HasValue ? myClass.Value : null;

Comment: @cinek Yes, in that case you've got the same logic as your `if/else`. The type of the ternary is `string`, not `MyClass<string>`, and so you never create a `MyClass<string>` which is null, and you never try and convert that null `MyClass<string>` into a string. I addressed that case earlier in my answer.